# Doctrine 2: How do i check if any result/object/row returned?

Tags: doctrine

i wonder in doctrine 2, how do i check if the query returned any result. say if i use the following ...

```
getXXXResult(); // eg. $result = $em->createQuery('xxx')->getXXXResult()
findXXX(); // eg. $obj = $em->getRepository('xxx')->findXXX();
```

i wonder what other methods are there to query for data in doctrine and how i can check if

- there are any rows returned
- how many rows returned/affected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found my answers in [Doctrine Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/b0fe08b9b3da3e41/22e036fe4674f619#22e036fe4674f619)

> how about executing `count()` on the
>   array result?
>
> You can use a method of the Collection
>   Array ... e.g.: `$users->count()`;